# Having problems with pushing angular app to Heroku because of Error in multi

Tags: angular, heroku

When I try to push to Heroku I get an error, and it doesn't allow me to push my app to Heroku.

I've tried to change the path in the angular.json file a bunch of times and nothing seems to work at all.

Here is part of my angular.json

```
"assets": [
              "src/assets/favicon.png",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
              "src/styles/global-styles.scss"
            ],
```

Here is my file/folder layout:

[image]

Here is my global-styles.scss file:

```
@import "~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss";
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
@import "./colors";
@import "./buttons";
@import "./links";
@import "./normalizer";
@import './vars';
@import './fonts';
```

I want this to be able to upload my app to Heroku, but instead it's giving me the error: `ERROR in multi ./src/styles.scss ../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css remote: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/tmp/node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css' in '/tmp/build_4f6eeca961bf1b3afe234677288429fd'`

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong at this point but I'm getting pretty frusterated. It looks like a path issue, but I cannot seem to figure out what path.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// in angular.json
    "build": {
      "options": {
        "styles": [
          "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
          "styles.css"
        ],
      }
    }
```

Ref:https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-include-font-awesome#using-css

Answer (score 0):

## angular.json

```
"root":"",
"styles":[
       "./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
]
```

If above not working:-

1) `"../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",`

2) Download font-awesome files and keep in assets and give path in angular.json or index.html as:-

```
"src/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css"
```

3)Or, Use CDN for fontawesome in index.html